# what it is the cause of Connection to http://31.170.160.102 refused?

Tags: android, mysql

in this [link](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/how-to-connect-to-mysql-by-php.html) they said:

> $db_host is the name of your MySQL server.
>
> Normally, it's called localhost at the default TCP/IP port 3306. If
>   you have installed MySQL with a different port number (only when you
>   install more than one MySQL Server on the same machine), you need to
>   add that information to $db_host like this:

however I am using freehost site , that have`mysql` , so I dont have it on my machine.

Is it correct if to $db_host to be 'localhost' ? 
because I tried adding localhost , and localhost:80 ( 80 is port number) and I find something in the site refer to host  I also added , I am having error

Now I added localhost:80 and I have the following error :

```
conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://31.170.160.102 refused
```

here is my ip in my code and yes I can ping it

private String URL_NEW_PREDICTION = "http://31.170.160.102/new_predict.php";

and yes I added permission

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
```

this is the congiq.php

```
<?php
 // Database configuration
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'a6901827');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '*****');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:80');
    define('DB_NAME', 'a6901827_justed');
?>
```

Comment: You should get the name of `MySQL server` from your **web-hosting provider**

Comment: @Ormoz I did put it and i got error from it , one moment ill show you the error

Comment: Are you sure your user name and password for the connection is correct? usually, the user name and password for connecting mysql is different from that of `ftp` or `cPanel`.

Comment: @Ormoz I dont know man I am working with 000webhost and they said I have to put all my files in publc_html .. I did that , then I login to the database with the same I add in the confiq.php ... I am still facing error

Comment: Go to `cPanel` then click on `MySQL` icon which is nearly at the bottom of the page. In the new page, you can create databases and also create users for them. For connecting to the db, you should use the username and password that you set in this page. Please tell me if you succeeded or not.

Comment: @ormoz i appreciat your help .. i left my lap nw .. whn i cm bak ill rply tnx

Comment: The name of db_server is also mentioned there. It is in the form of **mysql##.000webhost.com**

Comment: @Ormoz Can you check this question ? Exception : Connection to my ip refused

Comment: I transferred the conversation to chat

Comment: hey at least post your solution guys @Ormoz

Comment: @kumarkundan honestly i have forget the issue , post a new question and ill try to help you